# "Invalid set index (on base: null instance)" error

Tags: godot

I am trying to use a timer to change a variable in the parent node of the timer upon timeout.

```
func _on_DashTimer_timeout():
    get_node("root/Game/Level_1/Player").ACCELERATION = 10
    get_node("root/Game/Level_1/Player").MAX_SPEED = 50
    get_node("root/Game/Level_1/Player").velocity = get_node("root/Game/Level_1/Player").current_velocity
```

However, when I attempt to run it, it comes up with the error:

> Invalid set index 'ACCELERATION' (on base: null instance) with value of type 'int'

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: "null instance" sounds like a problem. Are you sure the "root/Game/Level_1/Player" node is being found?

Comment: You can accept your own answer. And doing so, you signal that this is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized I had to add a / before root. Hope this helps someone else who has this problem.